# Could not install [App] The requested app is not available or doesn't exist. in closed trials

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect, archive, testflight

I made the app file in xcode validate the app and then I shared it only in test fligth when I wanted to test it on my iphone 14 Plus device the following message appears :Could not install [App] The requested app is not available or doesn't exist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elzy6.jpg)

I try uploading other builds same thing happens with the other two apps.
I've been two weeks trying to solve this bug or problem, I searched for information on google but what appears is from 2014 how much appstore had the name of itunes Connect
[
[https://www.appleayuda.com/pregunta/8290/quotla-aplicacion-no-esta-disponible-intentalo-de-nuevoquot-en-testflight](https://stackoverflow.com) 
](https://stackoverflow.com)

, I have asked in other forums and ddicen to wait a while that is normal but I think it takes a long time. If someone has gone through this and put you solve agadeceria you can help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.